# Straight Line from Coast

Tags: qgis, line

I have a polyline representing a pier. I need to know if the angle of the polyline was continued straight what part of another country would it meet. I'm using EPSG:4326 and I have used the advanced digitizing toolbar to lock the angle of the polyline and then I extended it.

I'm trying to ascertain the most accurate way to achieve my answer. I'm using Natural Earth data. I don't need an answer more accurate than what can theoretically be achieved using Natural Earth data.

Comment: Are you interested in every country, or only the first? What data do you have?

Comment: Do you want to work using straight lines in lat-long cartesian coordinates, or straight lines as great circles on the sphere (or ellipsoid)?

Comment: Do you want or need to do it manually-ish in QGIS with a combination of clicks and tools? Or would a Python approach work as well?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the most accurate answer, I would suggest using a conformal projection (one that preserves direction). Mercator (EPSG:3395) would be a fine choice, you can read more about it [here.](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/mercator.htm)

EPSG:4326 is a coordinate system, not a projection so it will not provide you with as accurate an answer.

Comment: And how should OP go about determining which country is in the direction of interest?

Comment: OP indicated they are using Natural Earth data which includes countries and political subdivisions. The extended pier line will point to whatever country or region and they can ID it from that data.